# shall I do calculations in the Business Layer?

Tags: asp.net

Right now I am trying to apply the n-tier architecture to our web application, and I get the basic concept of every layer's functionality and relationships between these layers.
So the question is:
In which layer should I do calculations that are business related?
Thanks!

Comment: Precisely on the business layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In which layer should I do calculations that are business related?

The answer is in your question, the business layer. The presentation layer should simply tie your business logic to your UI. So the typical process is to retrieve data from the business layer and display it in the UI. Then you could allow the UI to alter the data and then pass it back to the business layer.

The basic idea is to keep the UI layer as thin as possible, and only let it perform logic related to the UI itself.

Comment: One item to note is that the business layer should not be accessing the persistence layer directly, ie...DB access

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question there. You should try your best to place all calculations related to business logic into the business logic layer. There is really nothing else I can add about this.